# Reading data from Google Datastudio Report

Tags: r, web-scraping, looker-studio

I wonder whether there is a way in R to read data directly from (daily) updated Google Datastudio Report. The option to download CSV data manually from each chart is enabled (after login), but I am looking for an automated way to download the data. I thought about using `rvest` to scrape the data, but it is not embedded in the code (my knowledge of html/css/javascript is very limited)...

The data is on current covid-19 cases in the Czech Republic, it is published by the government, but original data in flat files is unfortunately not supplied anywhere.

The Google Datastudio Report I wanna download the data from is here: https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/d0af39ad-3513-4ab9-a202-4afed1f786e2/page/DzlHB